# How to overlay images sequence from pipe over a video stream with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

I'm trying to figure out an issue with ffmpeg.
I have the following installation: 
- DeckLink Mini Recorder Card (for HDMI input)
- DeckLink Mini Monitor Card (for HDMI output)

I've successfully managed to take the HDMI input from the Decklink card and output is as-is to the output card with the following command:

`ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input hdmi -raw_format yuv422p10 -i "DeckLink Mini Recorder" -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink Mini Monitor"`

I tried to add a complex-filter to add an overlay of an image, with the following command, and it works:

`ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input hdmi -raw_format yuv422p10 -i "DeckLink Mini Recorder" -i ./tools/bin/windows/2.png -y -filter_complex "[0:1][1:0]overlay=10:10" -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink Mini Monitor"`

I'm getting a realtime feed from the decklink recorder, the image is added to the stream, and it outputs it to the output HDMI card. Everything seems to work.

Now I tried to change the static image path to use stdin (`pipe:0`), and I have a tool that constantly streaming PNG images to stdout:

`ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input hdmi -raw_format yuv422p10 -i "DeckLink Mini Recorder" -i pipe:0 -y -filter_complex "[0:1][1:0]overlay=10:10" -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink Mini Monitor"`

The result that i'm getting on the output HDMI card is a static image, of the first frame.
The output of ffmpeg also changes now, and it looks like it stuck of the first-second of the stream:

```
frame=   30 fps=7.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.247x

{ frames: 30,
   currentFps: 7,
   currentKbps: NaN,
   targetSize: NaN,
   timemark: '00:00:01.00' }
```

It just remains on `00:00:01.00` and never changes.

I tried to find the issue, and did the following:

- Tried to stream Decklink Recorder -> static png file overlay -> Decklink Monitor = **IS WORKS**
- Tried to stream static png file -> Decklink Monitor = **IS WORKS**
- Tried to stream pipe:0 (PNG files) -> Decklink Monitor = **IS WORKS**
- Tried to stream Decklink Recorder -> pipe:0 (PNG files overlay) -> RAW AVI file **IS WORKS**

The only issue is with:
- Tried to stream Decklink Recorder -> pipe:0 (PNG files) overlay -> Decklink Monitor **DOES NOT WORK**

I suspect that Decklink output is more strict, and my `pipe:0` with the PNG images is not stable, and the combination of both causes it to freeze.

Any idea how to solve it? :(

Thanks!

Comment: Share the full log of the freezing command with `-v 40`

Comment: @Gyan thank you for your response!
the full log is here:https://pastebin.com/07yjgXNs

Also, from time to time i'm also seeing `[decklink @ 000001acb9931800] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!` in the log, i'm not sure it's related because I see these message also with the working scenarios.

Comment: @Gyan just noticed that from time to time it does add more frames and the view changes, but it looks kind of random, and only the input from the PNG pipe:0 changes (with HUGE delay, and most of the frames are missing).
the stream from Decklink Mini Recorder remains with it's initial frame. I

Comment: BTW, the PNG streamer send a new PNG only each seconds, and not in a constant rate. maybe it's related?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try this

```
ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input hdmi -raw_format yuv422p10 -i "DeckLink Mini Recorder" \
       -framerate 1/10 -i pipe:0 \
    -y -filter_complex "[1]fps=5[i];[0:1][i]overlay=10:10" \
       -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink Mini Monitor"
```

where `10` in `1/10` represents the approximate duration in seconds between images sent out over the pipe.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan! 
With `-framerate 1/10` only - the background video works without freezing, but I can't see the overlay. I tried to use`"[1]fps=5[i];[0:1][i]overlay=10:10` with the complex filter (and with the framerate flag), but now it seems that it breaks the output, because my screen says that the input is not supported. maybe the order changed? I need to keep `0:1` as the main video stream, and the overlay should be on top.

Comment: Share the full log.

Comment: I added `-r` and `-s` to the output and not the input is valid. full log is here: https://pastebin.com/3rHZYJ6S . background video is working now, but the overlay seems to drop a lot of frames, it sometimes renders it, but mostly don't (looks a bit random). I figured out that the fact that i'm not seeing anything as overlay is because of the randomness of the drawing, if I'll wait a bit it sometimes renders one of it's frames.

Comment: Maybe it's still something related to framerate? I tried to force the png generator to create as much frames as possible (by taking screenshots of a video) and it looks better, so I guess that the issues is missing frames. Is there a way to force ffmpeg to duplicate frames if they are missing?

Comment: Your decklink input is 30 fps. Set `fps=` to that. What is the actual frequency of PNG generation? Drop the `-r` unless you need that output rate (drop frame is unusual for 50 fps). If you don't have audio content, add `-an` unless your output device needs it.

Comment: I have a free drawing tool that outputs PNG, and the output is depends on the drawings. which means that if the user is no drawing anything = there are no new PNGs. I tried to replace the free drawing with a video that transforms to PNG (much more frames) and it seems to work (small lag but it's fine for now). With the PNG of the free drawing everything seems to be frozen, and it renders it randomly. Audio is not important at the moment, tried to use `-an` but it didn't make any difference...

Comment: It seems like the overlay causing the main video to freeze because it's waiting for frames and input. Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to repeat the last frame until a new frame arrives?

Comment: The overlay filter won't bypass; that why the fps filter is inserted. I would suggest that you generate or stream a transparent PNG at startup and send that regularly. When user draws PNG, switch to that and repeat that till next PNG. You can also switch back to transparent PNG. Ideally, at same fps as main input.

Comment: Tried it now. I have a a code that runs every 1000/30 and writes a PNG (the last one) until he has a new one... it's still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172810/discussion-between-dotan-simha-and-gyan).